# save whatsapp login to file to load it to selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException


    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/geckodriver')
    driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')  # scans QR code and redirected
    driver.get('https://google.com')
    driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')  # is automatically in
    # driver.get_cookies() empty list
```

Is there a way to save the login so if I close the driver and re-open it, so I am also automatically logged in Whatsapp?

Ideally, I want to create a file so the driver reads from there and loads up the information of login.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't emulate WhatApp login, because of [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha).

Websites can easily detect network traffic and identify your program as a BOT. Google has already released 5 (five) reCAPTCHA to choose from when creating a new site.

[You can automate reCatcha passing only if you using **your** service](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq).